# Puma not starting after EC2 restart,bundler: command not found: puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2

I'm super new to Ruby and i was making an ami of EC2 and suddenly my EC2 cpu got high and i have to restart it. After that my Webapp is giving 502.
I ran this command but it is giving error

```
bundler: command not found: puma
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

The command is

```
bundle exec puma -e production -d -b unix:/home/deploy/council-data/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
```

Attached screenshot of error, I'm kind of lost don't know what to do make the app back running again. Any help would be great.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How's your Ruby installed? Also try running `bundle install` if that improves things!

Comment: @Babar Thanks! Does running bundle install can have problems in the future? Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: Umm, hope no. Whenever you deploy a new version, you'll run `bundle install` anyway!

Comment: Can u run `bundle install` properly on the same terminal? also, do you have `puma` gem enabled for `production` environment?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you install ruby , bundler and gems in other account which is not "admin" currently you are using. Try root account or deploy with "sudo bash".

Comment: getting this error now bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby2.3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: gem install bundler